# How to reload a TensorFlow model with TextVectorization with vocabulary?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have a TensorFlow model with the following structure:

```py
model = keras.Sequential()
model.add(keras.Input(shape=(), dtype=tf.string))
model.add(layers.TextVectorization(vocabulary=VOCAB_PATH, output_sequence_length=SEQ_LENGTH))
model.add(layers.Embedding(VOCAB_SIZE, SEQ_LENGTH))
model.add(layers.LSTM(SEQ_LENGTH, return_sequences=True))
model.add(layers.LSTM(SEQ_LENGTH, retrun_sequences=True))
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.2))
model.add(layers.Dense(SEQ_LENGTH, activation="relu"))
model.add(layers.Dense(SEQ_LENGTH, activation="relu"))
model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dense(NUM_CLASSES, activation="softmax"))
```

After training I save the model with `model.save(SAVE_PATH)`.

`VOCAB_PATH` is the path to a text file containing all the words of my corpus. I created it with the `get_vocabulary()` function of another `TextVectorization` instance after I adapted it to the corpus. I choose this approach because I want the model to be as self contained as possible. As you can see, I am feeding a string into the model without preprocessing except lower casing and removing special characters.

But when I reload the model with `keras.models.load_model(SAVE_PATH)` the following error occurs:

```
AssertionError: Some Python objects were not bound to checkpointed values, likely due to changes in the Python program: [<tensorflow.python.ops.lookup_ops.MutableHashTable object at 0x7069027dbe0>]
WARNING:tensorflow:Unresolved object in checkpoint: (root).layer-0._index_look_layer.lookup_table._initializer._filename
WARNING:tensorflow:A checkpoint was restored (e.g. tf.train.Checkpoint.restore or tf.keras.Model.load_weights) but not all checkpointed values were used. See above for specific issues.
```

How do I have to save the model so that I just need to transfer the model and vocabulary files and use it out of the box?